# Stored Procedure exec Output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My Code

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(max), @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max) SET @table = @meta+'_prize4winner' 
DECLARE @CNT2 VARCHAR(100)

SET @SQLQuery = 'if exists (Select * from [dbo].' + @table + ' where idCampaignLog =''' + convert(nvarchar, @ID) +''') exec InsertWinner ''' + convert(nvarchar, @meta) +''','''+ convert(nvarchar, @ID)
+''',null  else select ''you lose ''as winStatus'
--print @SQLQuery

execute SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQuery
```

How I can get the result from SP_Execute @SQLQuery as a OUTPUT, I tried many but still not find the way, thx

Comment: This look like SQL Server.. The syntax seems correct only that you need to mention `OUTPUT` on the parameter for the `SP_EXECUTESQL`

Comment: can you give me a sample from this code? so I just declare new, thend execute SP_EXECUTESQL '@SQLQuery', @out OUTPUT ???